# Testing equal to promise

Tags: scheme, racket

How do I test if the cdr of a stream is equal to promise?  I'm trying to write something that looks like this:

```
(equal? (stream-cdr s) #<promise>)
```

It tells me that the syntax # is incorrect, so what's the correct way to write this?

Comment: What stream library are you using? Racket's stream implementation? (doesn't look like it, because of the `stream-cdr` procedure) srfi/40? srfi/41? SICP-style odd streams? ad-hoc? (then post it as part of the question)

Comment: `#<...>` is how Racket prints values that are unreadable; you can't use that syntax in your program. You must create a promise using `delay`; see Óscar's answer.

Answer (score 2):

That won't work, a "promise" does not have a value - yet. The only way to find its value is by *forcing* it or otherwise evaluating it. Depending on how it was implemented it might be a function with no arguments, waiting to be called or a delayed object, waiting to be forced. It's kinda like a Heisenberg uncertainty principle situation - you can't know the value of an arbitrary promise *until* you evaluate it.

Of course, if you evaluate the promise the comparison is straightforward. Because it's not clear from the question what stream library is in use, I'll assume an ad-hoc odd streams implementation using `delay` (alternatively: `lazy`) and `force` (as defined in [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-24.html#%_sec_3.5)), like this:

```
(define-syntax stream-cons
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((stream-cons head tail)
     (cons head (delay tail))))) ; also works using `lazy` in place of `delay`

(define (stream-car stream)
  (car stream))

(define (stream-cdr stream)
  (force (cdr stream)))
```

As I said, the comparison will be straightforward *if* the promise is evaluated first:

```
(define promise (delay 42)) ; also works using `lazy` in place of `delay`
(define stream  (stream-cons 16 42))

promise
=> #<promise:promise>
(equal? (stream-cdr stream) promise)
=> #f
(equal? (stream-cdr stream) (force promise))
=> #t
```

Answer (score 1):

A `promise` is the return value of `delay` (and, in some Scheme dialects, `make-promise`).  You can test the equality of this value to anything that you please.  For example:

```
> (define my-promise (delay "I'll always be good"))
> (equal? "I'll always be good" my-promise)
#f      # a string is not a promise
```

In your particular case `#<promise>` is an unreadable printed representation of a Scheme value for a promise.  A printed representation is not a value and thus your Scheme implementation will complain ("can't read").  If instead, you had bound `#<promise>` to something, like `some-promise`, you could have tried:

```
(equal? (stream-cdr s) some-promise)
```

Note that a promise is not it's value; a promise, when forced, returns a value.  That is:

```
(equal? some-promise (force some-promise))
```

is rarely (never?) true.

Comment: R6RS does not have `make-promise`, and R7RS `make-promise` does not do what you think it does (it corresponds to SRFI 45's `eager`). R6RS doesn't seem to have promises in its core library, and R7RS's promises are created using `delay`, `delay-force` (`lazy`), and `make-promise` (`eager`).